# Преобразование столбца в строку. DataGrid. Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица с данными привязанная к DataGrid. Помогите преобразовать столбец в строку? В такой вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {
        }

        OpcClient myClient = new OpcClient("127.0.0.1", 3000, 64 * 1024);
        bool isConnected = myClient.Connect();
        if (isConnected)
        {
            string message = @"Random.Int1,Random.Int2,Random.Int4";
            byte[] data = Util.MakeMessage(message);
            myClient.SyncSend(data);
            myClient.AsyncRead();
            while (true)
            {
                if (myClient.RecivedAll)
                {
                    string msg = "";
                    bool b = Util.VeryfyMessage(myClient.RecivedData.ToArray(), out msg);
                    if (!b)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataTable dt = Util.JsonToDataTable(msg);
                        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
            myClient.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56252/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and--).